# Quiero retornar el valor de un Select con jquery o javascript puro pero no lo logro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esta seria la manera común, que funciona pero para mi caso no me sirveria asi:

```js
$('#preguntaSeleccionada').on('change', function(){ 
   var valorPregunta = $(this).val(); 
   console.log(valorPregunta); 
});
```

```html
 

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="select2" id="preguntaSeleccionada">
      <option selected="selected">Seleccionar...</option>
      <option value="pregunta1" selected="selected">Pregunta 1</option>
      <option value="pregunta2" selected="selected">Pregunta 2</option>
    </select>
```

Esta seria la forma que estoy intentando para guardar el valor y luego guardarlo en una variable, pero no me retorna el valor sino como el Select

```js
 

var valorPregunta = $('#preguntaSeleccionada').on('change', function() {
                      return $(this).val();
                    }); 
             console.log(valorPregunta);
```

```html
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select class="select2" id="preguntaSeleccionada">
            <option selected="selected">Seleccionar...</option>
            <option value="pregunta1" selected="selected">Pregunta 1</option>
            <option value="pregunta2" selected="selected">Pregunta 2</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Por qué dices que la primera no funciona?

Comment: Si funciona, pero no me funciona para mi caso porque tendria que seguir escribiendo codigo dentro de ese selector y quiero hacerlo afuera. Por eso estoy intentando que me retorne el valor y luego guardarlo pero nada

Comment: Entonces explica mejor lo que quieres lograr pues la pregunta es confusa

Comment: Bien, talvez ahora si

Comment: Es decir tu intención es que cada que el select cambie de valor entonces en la variable se almacene dicho valor en una variable? y poder obtener este valor por fuera del select?

Comment: Si, exactamente, pero no me retorna los valores

Comment: Es que el console.log solo lo uso para ver si me esta guardando el valor en la variable y,si, si la declaro afuera me sale undefined pero este no es el caso, en este me retorna pero no el valor de cada opcion del select. Proba ejecutar el segundo codigo que dejo arriba y veras que es lo que me retorna.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Declara una variable afuera para que puedas utilizarla a lo largo de tu código.

2.- Es normal que al tratar de mostrarla en consola por primera vez te salga `undefined` ya que aún no has seleccionado nada lo cual no es un error.

3.- Veo que a todas tus opciones les agregas `selected = selected` lo cual es un error. Te recomiendo que solo se la agregues a la opción por defecto.

4.- Te muestro un ejemplo con código para que puedas solucionar tu problema:

```
let select = document.querySelector('#preguntaSeleccionada');


let valorPregunta = null;

select.addEventListener('change',function(){
  
  valorPregunta = this.value;
})
```